# Are there thread(sort of) variables in js?

Tags: javascript

I don't know what to call these so I'll call them threads. What I mean by threads is when you push a button that triggers a chain of `js` code execution, that is one thread. If you press the button again, that is a new thread originating from the same place. So basically this continuum of execution initiated by whatever from start to finish.

Ok so what I'm trying to do is identify where the thread is coming from and/or where its been. For example, the code might flow like this:

> button A -> function 1 -> function 2

or this:

> button B -> function 3 -> function 1 -> function 2

They both end up in the same place and whatever data involved goes through at least partially the same processing. What I'm trying to figure out in function 2 is where this thread originated from, did it come from button A or B? Or another place all together?

One way I know how to is to do this:

```
<input type="button" value="A" onclick="this.from = 'button A'; function1();">

function1() {
    function2();
}

function2() {
    console.log(this.from);
}
```

since this travels throughout the thread, I can attach stuff to it, such as the property "from". However, in my case the thread needs to travel through some functions that alter *this* such as

```
this.objectMemberFunc = function() {}.bind(this);
```

and the property is lost. Despite me using `.bind(this)` all over the place, I have no clue as to how it actually works, I just know that it makes this refer to the object instances I'm making these functions in. Something tells me that I could maybe use bind to my advantage though so how could I use it to attach a property to my threads?

Comment: How about passing a `source` or `sender` parameter to the function, like an event handler, which I understand this is anyway?

Comment: Since [`thread`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) is already a well-known concept in computing, I think a different name should be used in your question.

Comment: What about pass an `event` -> `e.target` will be available in your function and you can compare it?

Answer (score 1):

*What I'm trying to figure out in function 2 is where this thread originated from, did it come from button A or B?* You may pass an `event` into your functions

```js
document.getElementById('btnA').addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
document.getElementById('btnB').addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);

function doSomething(e){
  alert(e.target.id)
}
```

```html
<button id="btnA">Click A</button>
<button id="btnB">Click B</button>
```

And then you will be able to identify which button has been pressed.

Thanks